# SmartOS - install a native compatible OS

Tags: smartos

I want to create a blank smart machine in SmartOS, not a KVM VM, and install from ISO.

Is this possible? Most docs I can find is about setting up VMs in KVM. I want to install an OS such as Illumos in a native zone within SmartOS. I do NOT want KVM to provide the virtualisation layer. I can do this blindfolded.

It may well be that it's not supported what I'm hoping to do. Perhaps I really only can create a native zone using a preset template. But wouldn't it be nice to have Illumos or OpenIndiana in native zone?

I have of course tried to copy an ISO to an existing smartmachines root, and boot it and guess what it didn't boot of the iso.

```
vmadm boot 9faeef49-aa24-4f24-b08b-eb6cec6d6ccc order=cd,once cdrom=/sol-11_1-text-x86.iso,ide    (scsi,virtio make no difference)
```

For all I can tell, the only way to get a zone VM in SmartOS is to use a template.

Is this even possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SmartOS - build my own smart machine](http://serverfault.com/questions/526368/smartos-build-my-own-smart-machine)

Answer (score 3):

The way to provide generic virtualization (i.e. running something like Illumos or OpenIndiana) on top of SmartOS is to use KVM, [per the documentation you were already referred to](http://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/How+to+create+a+Virtual+Machine+in+SmartOS) on [your previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/526368/smartos-build-my-own-smart-machine).

[Zones](http://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/Zones), like the FreeBSD Jails that inspired them, are NOT generic virtualization: they are a special "sub instance" of the core operating system, effectively a super-chroot-on-steroids. They [are created and managed differently, as is described in the documentation](http://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/How+to+create+a+zone+%28+OS+virtualized+machine+%29+in+SmartOS). This process requires a pre-built (or custom-created) image on SmartOS, per their documentation.

A Zone is not "bare metal virtualization": The zones share a common kernel with the hypervisor system. Because of this only SmartOS can run inside of a SmartOS zone (just like only FreeBSD can run inside a FreeBSD jail, and only Solaris can run inside a Solaris zone).
You *may* be able to get closely-related operating systems to function within a zone, but it would be unwise to attempt this in production, and certainly not supportable by the SmartOS team or any sane sysadmin.